# Multiple Asp.net webform websites (40 websites) in one roof as one website

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have 40 individual asp.net webform websites created for different purposes with different databases.

Now my task is to get all this in one roof.

Since everything is indivdual websites the user login credentials are available in separate tables with authorization rights from sql table which controlled in webconfig.

My problem is that each websites consist different Login Tables with user data.
One user is allowed in 4 websites.
One user may be allowed in 25 webites.
One user may be restricted to use only 1 website.
Tot user count is 3000.

What is the best approach to merge all this websites in one roof with same kind of individual website login authentication mode?

I tried to keep root level webconfig and folder level webconfig.  The root level webconfig will check the user login and allow to enter home page.

In Home page 40 websites are listed.  When user clicks any website it go to the concerned websites folder and act like individual website like current method.  But it is not working since folder level webconfig is not allowing to have authentication mode getting stored in it.

Any suggestion / direction will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you have all web sites under one site?

Then you would have a user role that secures each site, and if the user is not a member of that security group (role), then they would not be able to use that sub site.

So, you need/want 40 roles, and then you can have one logon, and then assign a role to that user for each web site.

with some kind of admin page, you could list out the sites (the role for each site) and have the admin check which sites they belong to.

So, assuming your using standard web security (most likly FBA), then you not have to write new or additional code for this to work. But then again, this also assumes that roles are the same for each site, since if security was used in each site - based on role of course, then you would have to keep the existing roles, and add one more new role to each user that allows use of the given site.